# Isomers of Pentaaminechlorocobalt(III) chloride

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, isomers

What kind of isomers does $\ce{[Co(NH3)5Cl]Cl2}$ exhibit?

I can rule out geometrical and optical due to there being $\ce{5 NH3}$ ligands which central metal atom cannot have different positions of $\ce{Cl}$ because there exists only one.

This does not show linkage isomerism because there is no bidentate or polydentate ligand for that , this does not show coordination or solvent isomerism because of No coordination second complex and no solvent in the chemical formula

Does this show ionization isomerism , as $\ce{NH3}$  could occupy the position of $\ce{Cl}$ in the front and we could have $\ce{[Co(NH3)3Cl3](NH3)2}$ but I am confronted on whether amine could occupy a counter ion's position where the counter ion exists to balance charge , yet there is no change of oxidation state of metal and then this transition could occur freely ?

Comment: Chemistry SE  (in contrary to some other SE sites) strongly recommends plain text question titles for index/search reasons and due possible displaying issues in question title lists.

Comment: Chem+Math Expression formatting reference:
 [MathJax Basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) / [Chem+Math expressions/formulas/equations](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) / [Upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) / [Math SE Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: But then the sum of charges does not fit. 
Possible are these:  $\ce{[Co(NH3)6]Cl3}$, $\ce{[Co(NH3)5Cl]Cl2}$, $\ce{[Co(NH3)4Cl2]Cl}$, $\ce{[Co(NH3)3Cl3]}$.

Comment: can we have $\ce{[Co(NH3)3Cl3](NH3)2}$

Comment: because Again for ionization isomerism , we get $\ce{2NH3}$as a product but , still not sure we can count this for ionization isomerism

Comment: How would be those 2 external NH3 bonded?

Comment: I am not sure @Poutnik , thats a very good question , I am just learning co-ordination compounds and my guess is that they are externally bounded just like the 2 chlorine atoms at the start bounded to the metal complex

Comment: Chlorides are ( in solid state) bound within ionic bond. That is not the case for ammonia. In solution is chloride and ammonia independent on the cationic or neutral complex . // Another thing could be ammonia solvates (analog to hydrates), but that may require liquid ammonia solvent.

Comment: Oh that makes sense!! The ligands give lone pair electrons , but counter ion is an ion and makes ionic bonds , which means $NH3$ cannot bond hence we can conclude this complex has no ionization Isomers !

Comment: then possibly it can be solvate isomerism @Poutnik